# Recurring contributions fail with PayPal Pro - "DPRP is disabled for this client"

Tags: paypal, recurring-contributions

We recently set it so that members can sign up for a recurring donation.  All of our payments for recurring donations are failing, though. You can see in the attached picture that there are three failed recurring payments.  One of them is mine, and I know that I entered the payment information correctly, so the payment should not have failed.  I've recently, successfully, made other payments on this site with the exact same payment information.

We recently upgraded to CiviCRM 5.3.2 from 4.6.28.  We are using Drupal 7.60.
We are using PayPal as our payment processor.

List of recent contributions, showing failed recurring payments:
[image]

Membership page for my membership, showing pending membership and failed payment.
[image]

Comment: you might want to add info about what Payment Processor you are using. Also your screenshot shows actual names, you might want to anonymise it

Comment: What Pete said - different payment processors handle recurring payments differently.  What works for iATS isn't what works for PayPal, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it.  The payment processor is PayPal.

Comment: PayPal offers various options eg PayPal Express, Paypal Website Payments Pro etc. You should be able to figure which it is by looking at /civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor?reset=1,

Comment: Just to confirm, have you seen the money taken from your account from your test of the process?  There are multiple points at which the process could fail, and identifying the point at which things broke can help you troubleshoot. If the payment was processed in Paypal, I'd check the logs to see if you received any info back.  (I'm assuming you updated the IPN in Paypal to send the notifications.)

Comment: No, the money has not been taking from my account.

Comment: We are using PayPal Website Payments Pro.

Comment: can you accept your own Answer to close this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ends up that the issue was that we do not have the Recurring Payments module enabled in our PayPal account.  When someone submits a recurring contribution, they get a warning stating "DPRP is disabled for this client".